In Texas, can repeat mailing fees be subtracted from the rental security deposit
Assume a tenant gave a landlord an address that was wrong.  The landlord has sent the security deposit via certified mail, and the tenant then says the receiver didn't accept the delivery and the check is being returned to sender.  The tenant gives a new address and now the landlord must send another certified mail.  Is it legal for the landlord to deduct the first certified mailing from the security deposit?
(And as an aside, does the new address start a new 30 requirement to return the security deposit, or does that still remain as 30 days after move-out day?)
